# Possible NullReferenceException ReSharper code analysis C#

Tags: c#, resharper

ReSharper code analysis tells me that in following code snippet

```
if (users.Select(a => a.id).Contains(user_id))
{
    return users.FirstOrDefault(a => a.id == user_id).type == 2;
}
```

the line `return users.FirstOrDefault(a => a.id == user_id).type` might result in a possible `System.NullReferenceException`. Is this true given that I already check whether this specific `user_id` exists in the `users` container?

```
class users
{
   int id {get; set;}
   int other_stuff {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this true given that I already check whether this specific `user_id` exists in the `users` container?

Yes, this is warning is correct, because `users` may be changed concurrently between the call to `Contains` and the call to `FirstOrDefault`. ReSharper's logic analyzer does not assume exclusive access to the container, so issuing a warning is the right behavior.

You can fix this warning with a null-conditional operator:

```
var optType = users.FirstOrDefault(a => a.id == user_id)?.type;

if (optType.HasValue) {
    return optType == 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that you have such element in your collection then you can just use `.First`:

```
if (users.Select(a => a.id).Contains(user_id))
{
     return users.First(a => a.id == user_id).type == 2;
}
```

However, it is better to use `.FirstOrDefault` and null check instead of `Contains` so that you don't lookup your collection twice:

```
var foundItem = users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == user_id);
if (foundItem != null)
{
    return foundItem.type == 2;
}
```